# Make p-retry function with promises

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I want to write my owm promisified retry function, spesifically the [p-retry](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-retry) function that returns promise (not callback).

And I want to make a generic function that promisifies for example `readFile` function as an argument that retry function takes.

I'm writing it in typescript for more readable code. However, I'm facing an issue because when I pass the readFile function it throws an error `this type of argument is not assignable to ...`

Can you give me a hint please what am I doing wrong? I'm kinda beginner with typescript so I know it's not probably writen exactly how it should be...

```
const promisifyRetryFun = <T>(fn: (
  input: () => Promise<T> | T ,
  options?: { retries?: number }
) => Promise<T>) =>
  async (path: string, maxRetries: number) => {
      let attemptCount = 0
      const result = <T>(): Promise<T> => 
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          (fun: (path: string, callback: (error: Error, result: any) => void) => void) => {
              fun(path, async (error, result) => {
                if(attemptCount >= maxRetries) reject(error)
                if(error) fn(await result(), {retries: maxRetries})
                attemptCount++
                resolve(result)
              })
          }
        })
      fn(await result(), {retries: maxRetries})
  }

void (async () => {
  try{
    const retr = promisifyRetryFun(retry(readFile))
    const data = await (retr('./txt.txt', 3))

  } catch (error) {
    console.error({ error })
  }
})()
```

Comment: What is `retry`?

Comment: Don't write one function that does both things at once. Write one function for retrying promise-returning functions, write another function for promisifying callback-accepting functions (or just use `util.promisify`). Then use `retry(promisify(readFile))`.